# Hadoop is not starting any datanode on windows 7

Tags: java, hadoop, windows-7-x64, shutdown

I build hadoop on win7-x64. I configured hadoop and when I run hadoop, it was failed to starting datanodes. It shows the following error. It shutting down datanode. How can I fix this error? Thanks.

```
14/08/01 07:36:23 FATAL datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for block pool
Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to localhost/127.0.0
.1:9000
java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in C:\hadoop\data\dfs\datanode: nam
enode clusterID = CID-72be3471-e6d9-4c1a-9d2c-d66938de8c93; datanode clusterID =
 CID-0000641d-13c0-41cd-ad5b-fd5854906ad0
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.doTransition(DataS
torage.java:472)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionR
ead(DataStorage.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionR
ead(DataStorage.java:249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.
java:929)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNod
e.java:900)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.verifyAndSetNam
espaceInfo(BPOfferService.java:274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.connectToNNAndH
andshake(BPServiceActor.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceAc
tor.java:815)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Make life easy for yourself, use a sensible operating system.  Stick to using windows for MS Word - as for serious work, stick to linux/unix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem, 
Just remove dfs.namenode.name.dir and dfs.datanode.data.dir properties in hdfs-site.xml

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case you just circumvented the problem. You would go better cleaning the hfds data directories, cleaning /tmp/hadoop-[username] files and re-formatting the namenodes, then starting all the services from the scratch.